# Why does float.parse return wrong value?

Tags: c#, parsing, floating-point, numbers, floating

I have a problem. when I parse a string like "0.005" to float or double, it works fine on my computer, but when i install my program to my client's computer, it returns 5. (both my computer and my client's computer are using Windows 7 x64). Here are my examples

```
public float getFloat()
    {
        float mn = float.Parse("0.005");
        double mn2 = Convert.ToDouble("0.005");
        return mn;
    }
```

Comment: Are you guys using the same culture in your machines? `.` is not the decimal separator in every culture. **Edit:** In PT-BR, for example, 0.005 **IS** 5.

Comment: that's an interesting broblem you have there.

Comment: Yes, the problem is almost definitely that your client's computer is set to use "." as a thousands separator rather than a decimal point, as @Renan alludes to.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It could be problem with system culture settings. Try this:

```
float.Parse("0.005", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```